# Is the phrase "не маєш клепки" considered offensive?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів, фразеологізми

I'm not sure about the usage of this phrase.

I've heard/seen the phrase "у тебе немає клепки в голові" when people (as I thought) are talking about someone's incompetence.

Is that the only meaning?

And is the phrase "не маєш клепки" considered offensive?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The noun *клепка* means "one of the convex [staves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stave_(wood)), planks of which a barrel, a cask is made" and the Ukrainian Language Dictionary in 11 volumes [lists](http://sum.in.ua/s/klepka) several idioms of the same meaning, "to be foolish, out of one's mind", they all have the remark *зневажл[иве]*, "derogatory":

> - Клепки розсохлись - "[somebody's] staves have cracked from dryness"
> - Клепку загубити - "to loose a stave"
> - Немає (не вистачає, бракує) однієї (третьої, десятої і т. ін.) клепки [в голові] - "[somebody] lacks one (the third, the tenth, etc.) stave [in the head]"

And one more:

> - Клепку вставляти (вставити) - "to insert a stave [into somebody's head]" - "to edify somebody, to give a lesson to somebody". This last idiom has the *"ironic"* remark.

So, if you say that to a person you barely know, it can be taken as an offense, but while talking with friends and said jokingly, it will be taken with a smile. Still, those idioms are about somebody's mental abilities, so use them reasonably. ))